# How to Enable vault feature in custom payment module

Tags: magento2.3, payment-methods, vault

We are generating payment token against credit card for this we build a custom payment module which is working fine, now we want to enable the customer to save the card and choose saved card during the checkout to make the checkout process faster.

We wil not make any transacton when the customer will choose the saved card as the payment token will remain the same. we will just complete the order and update the credit card and token information afte the order will placed.

To accomplish this we will use Vault feature.can someone help in enabling vault in custom payment module.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Event Observer. on sales_order_payment_save_before event, get all the order info.

```
 public function execute(EventObserver $observer) {
        $paymentOrder = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment();
       
        $order = $paymentOrder->getOrder(); }
```

Then use this data (credit card, expiry date, cvv) to create token. Then save it in sales_order_payment table.

```
 $inputParams = $this->_inputParamsResolver->resolve();        
        foreach ($inputParams as $inputParam) {
            if ($inputParam instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment) {
                $paymentData = $inputParam->getData('additional_data');
            
                    $cc_card_num =  $paymentData['cc_number'];
                    $paymentOrder->setAdditionalInformation('Expiration Month ', $paymentData['cc_exp_month']);
                    $paymentOrder->setAdditionalInformation('Expiration Year ', $paymentData['cc_exp_year']);
                    $paymentOrder->setAdditionalInformation('Name ', $paymentData['cc_owner']);
                    $paymentOrder->setAdditionalInformation('Ext. ', $paymentData['cc_ext']);
                    $paymentOrder->setAdditionalInformation('Phone', $paymentData['cc_phone']);        
                    $paymentOrder->setAdditionalInformation('order_placed', 1);        
                    if(isset($paymentData['cc_cid'])){
                        $paymentOrder->setAdditionalInformation('CVV', $paymentData['cc_cid']);
                    }                            
            }
        }
```

In your Payment.php file, you can just define validate method, don't include the capture method.

```
 * Pay In Store payment method model
 */
class PaymentMethod extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Cc
{ }
```

Ask me, for further guidance.

Comment: Thank you Jasvir, actually am looking for Magento vault feature to use in the custom module. rest all the things are working fine

For Reference 
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/payments-integrations/vault/